# A question on the classifying space $BG$, its universal property (?), and the stack $[\bullet/G]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

I am learning about the classifying space $BG$ of a topological group $G$. I know the definition $$BG=EG/G,$$ where $EG$ is any contractible space on which $G$ acts freely.
If I am not mistaken, with this definition we are viewing $BG$ as an object in the homotopy category.

On Wikipedia there is a reference to the functor $F_G$ from the homotopy category to the category os sets, sending a space $Z$ to the set of principal $G$-bundles over $Z$, up to isomorphism.

> **Question 1.** Does the couple $(BG,EG\to BG)$ always represent this
>   functor?

Let us now leave the topological category and move to the category of (group) schemes. I am thinking about the relationship existing in general between
$$BG \,\,\,\,\,\,\textrm{and}\,\,\,\,\,\,[\bullet/G].$$
I wrote down what $BG$ is, I wrote down what $[\bullet/G]$ is (I know the definition of it as a stack), and I suspect they should be the same thing. But in the stack world one does usually not divide by automorphisms, so if $BG$ happens to represent the functor $F_G$, then I should conclude (?) that $[\bullet/G]$ is always a scheme.

> **Question 2.** Do we always have $BG=[\bullet/G]$?

(In my questions, "always" means respectively: "for every topological group", and "for every group scheme".)
I hope that you can see where my confusion comes from, and that someone will kindly help me to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: And what do you mean by 'the couple ... represents this functor'? Functor can be represented by an object of the category. Yes, $BG$ represents $F_G$.

Comment: By "couple" I wanted to emphasize that $EG\to BG$ is the universal principal $G$-bundle. And yes, I meant group scheme (I did write it, actually).

Comment: If $G$ is a group scheme, what is $EG$ and $BG$? There are two problems here: (1) you want $EG$ to be contractible — and it's not clear what it should mean for schemes; (2) in all interesting cases $EG$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: So my second question does not make sense? that's a perfectly possible answer! I just wonder if it can make any sense at all. I recall I heard about $BG$ in the context of algebraic geometry (before knowing what it was), but maybe $[\bullet/G]$ is what they meant. I don't know.

Comment: I don't know enough about stacks to be very helpful (I'm learning them this summer), but perhaps this is helpful "If $G/S$ is a smooth group scheme, the *classifying stack* of $G$ is the stack quotient $[S/G]$ where $G$ acts trivially on $S$." This sort of looks like it answers your question. This is from Martin Olsson's book, which is still in preparation (you can email him for a copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In algebraic geometry, if $G$ is a smooth group scheme over $S$, then $BG$ denotes the algebraic stack $[S/G]$ over $S$ (as Alex Youcis remarks in a comment).

By definition, this classifies the "functor in groupoids" which to each $S$-scheme $T$ attaches the groupoid of locally trivial (in either the flat, smooth, or etale topology --- it should be equivalent in this context) principal $G$-bundles over $T$.

If you adopt a simplicial point of view, in which you use simplicial constructions to define stacks and higher stacks, than you can describe $BG$ via the usual simplicial construction.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer, together with the above comments, clarifies the point.